# Adding external jar file in maven project

Tags: maven, jar, redis

I need to add a JAR file in maven project for **redis** database connection. I added JAR file but problem is project give exception as i instantiate jedis object (this is indication that JAR file is not added correctly)

Please guide me how can i add external JAR file in maven based project

Comment: show us the code how are trying to add it ?

Answer (score 1):

Standard way in Maven to do this is to provide through dependency and tell maven I need this jar , can you please get it for me. Below is the details that will help you(maven) to identify the jar.

```
       <dependency>
           <groupId>groupid.of.your.jar</groupId>
           <artifactId>name.of.your.jar</artifactId>
           <version>version.of.jar</version>
     </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified which Redis library you're using.....

[Jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) is available from [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Credis.clients%7Cjedis%7C2.1.0%7Cjar), so try adding the following to your POM:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
    <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I am using jredis library and have added following dependency in POM  

  `<dependency>
   <groupId>jedis</groupId>
   <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.0</version>
   <scope>compile</scope>
  </dependency>`

Comment: @HaiderAli  There is only one search result for the artifactid "jedis" in Maven Central: http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22jedis%22 That means you are using a Maven repostory manager (like Nexus) or you have installed the jar into the local repository on your machine. You're best advised to use the Maven central GAV coordinates. Simpler to maintain going forwards and you'll get updates automatically.

Comment: **Thanks so much for replay** I think i have gone through all the steps correctly but still i am getting this error  
` ThreadExceptionHandler.uncaughtException()  SEVERE: Uncaught thread: "session-open Queue Worker 3" exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: redis/clients/jedis/Jedis`

Comment: @HaiderAli That class is included in that jar... http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|%20fc%3A%22redis.clients.jedis.Jedis%22%20AND%20g%3A%22redis.clients%22%20AND%20v%3A%222.1.0%22  Since you've accepted the answer I assume this is now fixed.